# Using find_element_by_xpath to extract img alt value coming up empty

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I don't receive an error or anything to tell me what's wrong, the list I'm appending the value to is just coming up empty. In my code, getting the values for variables page_cards, ticker, and optCriteria all work. I've tried following, following-sibling, and several other variations with no luck.

```
try:
    page_cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//article[@data-testid="tweet"]')
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue

for card in page_cards:
    try:
        ticker = card.find_element_by_xpath('//span/a[starts-with(text(),"$")]').text.replace('$', '')
        optCriteria = card.find_element_by_xpath('//span/a[starts-with(text(),"$")]'
                                                 '/../following-sibling::span').text.split('\n')[0].replace('-', '').replace('$', '')
        emoji = card.find_element_by_xpath('//span/a[starts-with(text(),"$")]/..//'
                                           'following-sibling::img[@alt= "Ox" OR @alt= "Bear face"]/@alt')
        tradeCriteria = str(ticker+optCriteria+emoji)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait

def wait_element_visible(self, delay, *locator):
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located(locator)
    )
```

Comment: Also get it out of the try except in order to receive error, must likely it doesn't find the element that's why you should add the wait function

Comment: Could you please add some description of what your solution would do?

Comment: yeah sure, basically it will wait for the component that you are trying to find to be visible.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By,    

example for locator:     locator = (By.Xpath, "'//div[contains(text(), "some text")]'")

Comment: Not in the comment section. Add with your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: So do I just call this function right after my emoji line? What does the locator parameter do and where do I get that?

Comment: First of all remove the try except, see what element specifically he can't find, after that use the wait function for the specific element you can't find, the locator is something you create, locator = (By.XPATH, "enter your xpath here")

Comment: I removed it from the try except and it gave me an error saying the emoji line is not a valid xpath expression. I then took the OR @alt = "Bear face" out of the expression and it just gave me the error that the element wasn't found. The desired emojis aren't in every tweet, so that's why I was using the try except. I've added a picture to my question to hopefully give a better understanding of where I'm trying to pull the emoji from.

Comment: Add the wait function you might try to find the element before it was loaded, I sent an example of wait in my answer, you can examine this theory by adding time.sleep(4) and see if he finds. Assuming your xpath is locating the element...

Comment: It looks like it's unable to locate the element. I'm getting this error now: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span/a[starts-with(text(),"$")]/..//following-sibling::img[@alt= "Ox"]/@alt"}
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.99)

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.